# Recursive even function issue with understanding (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, recursion

The problem is very simple, I have a function from 'Javascript Allonge' book, and having a hard time in understanding it.

The function is called even, and it's as follows:

```
var even = function(num) {
    return (num === 0) || !(even(num -1));
}
```

it checks whether the number is even or not, but I do not understand how. It calls itself recursively, and technically, always reaches zero, no? How does that work?

Comment: Step through it manually when `num` is `1`, and note that it works. Then try doing it with `2`.

Comment: _How does that work?_ What do you exactly mean? How it reaches zero?

Comment: Presumably the lesson from the book must be "don't ever write code like this." Your fellow developers will never forgive you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is based on an inductive definition of numbers being odd or even - a number, `n` is 'even' when the number before it, `n - 1` is odd.  This thinking naturally makes sense - 4 is even if 3 is odd.

And so the function `even` is defined as:

**1. `even(0)` is true - because 0 is even**

**2. `even(n)` is the negation of `even(n - 1)`**

Another way to think of it is imagine `even(4)` being called step by step.  By hand, replace the even(4) with result of evaluation it with your function:

```
even(4)
= !(even(3))
= !(!even(2))
= !(!(!even(1))
= !(!(!(!even(0)))
= !(!(!(!true))
= true


// ...even(4) == true
```

Comment: best and most precise answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, divide and conquer.

First of all you have two expressions to calculate. The first one is just stopping the recursion at the point when the number is 0, this is easy.

The second expression

```
!(even(num -1))
```

is a bit more complicated. It always starts with a call `even(num -1)` and then negates it.

For the first element `!(even(num -1) === true)`, so now you see that for every second element starting from 1 (1, 3, 5 etc.) it will return `false`, for others the inverted value.

Answer (score 0):

But there is a negation on the recursive call to `even`, so that, for every activation record on the stack, the return value gets inverted:

```
0 --> true
1 --> true --> false
2 --> true --> false --> true
```

Answer (score 0):

This function indeed calls itself recursively, but with an added inversion each time. `return (num === 0)` returns `true` when `num` equals zero. If `num` is greater than zero, it calculates the result of `even(num-1)` and inverses it.

So, with `num = 1`, the function returns the inverse of `even(0)`, which is `true`, making the end result `false`. With `num = 2`, the function returns the inverse of `even(1)`, which we've just shown to be `false`, making the end result `true`. The same principle applies for all integers.